# Run the code on program start-up

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I’m using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

to open Safari and redirect to a URL.

Where can I put this code in so as to let the program run this code at start-up?

At the beginning, I have the file of "HelloWorldViewController.h", "HelloWorldViewController.m" and "HelloWorldViewController.xlb" that are generated by XCode 4.

Updated, I added the code as below to xxxx.m file, but not works, please help

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
}
```

Comment: You want to immediately close your app and launch Safari on startup?!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you want to run it on statup then....

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

This is in the App Delegate....not sure **why** you would want to do this or whether Apple would even approve such an app...?

If you want to show web content then you can use a UIWebview and load the URL into that....