# Start-up function of a program

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to execute a code snippet when program start-up, so what is the start-up function of iOS program?

For Android program, the start-up function is **onCreate** as below

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       ...
```

How about iOS program?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run the code on program start-up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355151/run-the-code-on-program-start-up)

Comment: The answer of the previous post is not as detailed as I want

Comment: @Charles Then you’re expected to edit your original answer and provide more details as to what you want as an answer instead of posting a duplicate question. See the section ‘What if I don’t get a good answer?’ in Stack Overflow’s FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I have leave a comment but no one feedback me by 1 day, so I find for help by asking this question

Comment: The answer you accepted for your other question is identical to the answer you accepted here. Why did you accept the answer if it's not working for you?

Comment: Ok, I changed to not to accept the answer on the identical question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In iOS you use the [UIApplicationDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) in order to be informed of application lifecycle events (startup, suspend, shutdown, etc.):

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
}
@end

@implementation MyAppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    //start-up code here

    return YES;
}
@end
```

Assuming that you are using XCode for your iOS project, it will have created a default `UIApplicationDelegate` class for you.  All you need to do is find it and edit the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method to your liking.

Comment: I was so busy making sure I didn't miss any of the other options, I completely forgot about the most obvious. +1

Comment: @ughoavgfhw i do that all the time... :)

Answer (score 5):

The `main` function is called to begin the program. It is found in `main.m` in the templates in Xcode. You can also use `__attribute__((constructor))` to mark a function for execution before the program begins, or create a `+load` or `+initialize` method on a class. `+load` methods are called when a class is loaded into memory, before the program begins, but not everything will be loaded at that point. `+initialize` is called automatically before any other method in the class it is defined in, after the program starts.

Comment: While technically and absolutely correct, these are probably not the best options for a novice.